# Data does not send to controller

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a project of an online forum with Laravel 8, and in this project, I have a "Like" button at Blade like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.likes', $show->id) }}" method="POST">
   @csrf
   <button class="btn">
     <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
   </button>
</form>
```

**`$show->id` is the question id**

And here is the route `questions.likes`:

`Route::post('questions/{id}/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes');`

And then I called the Controller `LikeController` with the `store` method which goes like this:

```
public function store(Request $request, Question $id)
    {
        dd('output')
    }
```

But now the problem is it does not send data to this method, I mean when you click the button nothing happens at all!

So what is going wrong here?

If you would like to take a look at all the routes in the `web.php` file, [here it is](https://www.paste.org/117660).

Comment: is there any error? if not where it redirects to after submitting the form

Comment: @Joseph no error at all

Comment: I think it may be a route conflict so to make sure of that try to move your route line to line 19

Comment: If nothing happens then it's not (necessarily) an issue with the routing or controller. See if there is something else preventing the form to be submitted (e.g. some JS handler that is accidentally applied).

Comment: The controller names should be pluralized. Did you not create it as `LikesController`?

Comment: @Jonathan I don't understand about pluralization of Controller names ! My Controller is named `LikeController` and it it included at `web.php`. Can you add reference about using pluralized Controllers ...

Comment: did you try to clear your cache? `php artisan view:clear && php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0):

You will have to change `store(Request $request, Question $id)` to `store(Request $request, Question $question)`. Laravel will automatically resolve the provide `$show->id` argument to the `Question` model if you use the following route:

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes');
```

Comment: The route needs to be changed aswel, I updated the example

Comment: Thanks, but I got the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67970156/laravel-8-why-dd-does-not-appear-at-method/67970490#67970490

Answer (score 0):

```
<button type="submit" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

Set a type for your button, check if it works or not