# Laravel 8: Why dd() does not appear at method

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I have a **button** like this:

```
<form action="{{ route('questions.likes') }}" method="POST">
     @csrf
     <button class="btn" role="submit">
          <i class="fas fa-thumbs-up"></i>
     </button>
</form>
```

**Route**

```
Route::post('questions/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes');
```

**Controller**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        dd('output');
    }
```

But when I try it, I get this error:

`404 not found`

So why is it showing this instead of `dd()` ?

Comment: can you show routes

Comment: @JohnLobo Here are the full routes: https://www.paste.org/117660

Comment: `role="submit"` to `type="submit"`

Comment: you have pass id in route  action="{{ route('questions.likes') }}"

Comment: Your route is really `questions/{id}/thumbsUp`, not `questions/thumbsUp`, and you're not passing in the id.

Comment: @KamleshPaul I tried that but didn't solve the problem

Comment: You are working in localhost?

Comment: @Gass Yes I do.

Comment: you have two routes matching  Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}', [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers'); and Route::post('questions/{id}/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes'); so change order

Comment: @JohnLobo I didn't pass any parameter

Comment: pass paramter or else no similar route matching

Comment: @JohnLobo Yes I changed order and it works fine! Can you add it as answer and explain why it happens. The routes uri were different, I don't get the reason behind this.

Comment: in your .env do you have the APP_DEBUG set to true?

Comment: @Gass `APP_DEBUG=false`

Comment: oaky.will explain you in detail in my answer

Comment: set it to true ..

Comment: @Gass I did but what is the point of that? This is because of routing problems, but thanks anyway.

Comment: You get the same?

Comment: @Gass Yes if I don't make changes to routes as John Lobo suggests, I get the same error

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two routes which matches form submitting url.Because both has 3 segments with same pattern.

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}', [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
Route::post('questions/{id}/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes');
```

Form submitting route url is `questions/{id}/thumbsUp` but if you see `routes` , it matches to the `first route` since `first route` has `two dynamic parameters`.So request is going to first route.

So whenever `dynamic routes` then better add `static routes` first to match then dynamic routes.

Also you can add `regular expression` to routes to avoid conflicts. For example the below only allowed numbers

```
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}', [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers')->where('id', '[0-9]+');
```

So your route order should be.

```
Route::post('questions/{id}/thumbsUp' , [LikeController::class, 'store'])->name('questions.likes');
Route::post('questions/{question}/{asker}', [QuestionController::class, 'postAnswer'])->name('questions.answers');
```

Ref:https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints